# Ancient git repo vs modern git cloned copy, CRLF vs LF line endings

Tags: git

If this is a duplicate, please point me to it.

The problem I am confronted with is that immediately after cloning from a repository, `git status` says that a huge number of files have changed. I haven't changed a thing; I just cloned from the repo. The problem is CRLF vs LF line endings.

Relevant facts:

- The repo is on a Unix machine that runs an ancient version of git, version 1.7.1.
- The repo was populated via an Eclipse plug-in from a machine that uses a CRLF line endings and that has a somewhat modern version of git (exact version number unknown).
- My machine uses LF line endings and has a modern version of git, version 2.3.0.

All the text files have CRLF line endings when I clone the repo. That's fine; my machine can respect that. What isn't fine is that `git status` says that every text file has been changed. This is unacceptable; I haven't changed a thing (yet).

I have control over the git config and git attributes on my machine and on the repo machine. I don't have control over the version of git on the repo machine, or on how git was used on the machine that uses CRLF line endings.

**The question:**
What settings, either locally or on the repo, will enable me to clone that repo and have `git status` say nothing has changed?

**Update:**
Please don't tell me to:

- Use `git config --global core.autocrlf <value>`
  Please don't tell me that for two reasons.

  One reason is that even if it did work, this is not the solution I want. Most of my use cases involve people who use machines that use LF rather than CRLF line endings. Somehow, those nasty CRLF line endings manage to sneak their way in (this was a big problem with subversion). Modern versions of git snip that problem in the bud. In this one case, I'm dealing with someone who works with an industry that is very CRLF centric. This one case is the exception, not the rule. Please do not tell me to use `git config --global` to handle this special case.

  The other reason is that it doesn't work. I've already tried that. I've tried lots of things, but I always get `git status | grep modified: | wc -l` being a large number. It should be zero.

Answer (score 1):

If the global or local core.autocrlf setting is not getting the results that you want, you can set a git line ending attribute and force the result that you are looking for.

```
# Set eol conversions on all text-based files to 'nothing'
echo '* text' >> .gitattributes
# Force git to re-scan dir
rm .git/index
git reset
# Review current files
git status
```

Note: Normally the eol setting would be:

```
* text=auto
```

Comment: I already tried that; it doesn't work (both options). `git status` says all files with CRLF endings have been changed. The CRLF endings are in the repo and in the checked-out files. There's no difference, but git thinks there is. Note: I also tried making this setting in the git config file on the server. That doesn't work, either. In the clone, git thinks every text file has been changed.